# PHPEXCEL to store entries in an array and display

Tags: php, phpexcel

Here is the extract of my code that display  the excel entries and stores into array  .

The logic is first, detect which entry is invalid , mark it down, then for other valid entry, check whether it is duplicate, if it is, mark it down.

Eventually , scan through the whole sheet again, retrieve all the entries that is not in that two list. (duplicate or invalid)

The problems of it are:

1) When i display the table, although it can display but  it warns me that "
datatables warning:Request unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row 0"

2) When i store into array, it can only store for the first line of row

So , i would like to know are there any mistake in my looping logic? and had i used the PHPEXCEL to read spreadsheet in a correct way? Thank you.

```
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($readerType);
$PHPExcel = $reader->load($file);
$sheet = $PHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($sheet->getHighestColumn());

$pattern="/^[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$/";

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){
for ($head = 0; $head < $highestColumn; $head++){
$testMail = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($head, $row)->getValue();
if (preg_match($pattern,$testMail))
$mailColumn=$head;
}}
if(!isset($mailColumn))
{die('No email column detected, please check your file and import again.');}


$invaild[] = NULL ;
$email[] = NULL ;
$duplicate[] = NULL ;

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $highestColumn; $y++) {
    $val = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($y, $row)->getValue();

    if ($y == $mailColumn && !preg_match($pattern,$val))
    {$invaild[]=$row;}
    elseif ($y == $mailColumn && in_array($val,$email))
    {$duplicate[]=$val;
    $duplicate[]=$row;}
    //elseif (!in_array($row,$duplicate) && !in_array($row,$invaild) )
    //{echo $val;}

    if ($y == $mailColumn)
    {$email[]=$val;
    $email=array_unique($email);}

  }
}
$invaild=array_unique($invaild);


foreach ($invaild as $c)
{echo $c;}
echo "<br>";
foreach ($duplicate as $d)
{echo $d;}

?>


<div id="stylized" class="view">
<h1><?echo $file.' Result';?></h1> 
<p>Import from spreadsheet files</p>
   <div id="container">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="viewImport">
<thead>
<tr>

<?
for ($head = 0; $head < $highestColumn; $head++){
if ($head==$mailColumn)
echo "<th field='col'$head> Email address </th>";
else
echo "<th field='col'$head> Unname coloum $head </th>";
}
?>
</tr>
</thead>

<?
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($y = 0; $y < $highestColumn; $y++) {
        if (!in_array($row,$duplicate) && !in_array($row,$invaild)){
            $val = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($y, $row)->getValue();
            echo "<td>";
            if (!$val)
            echo "-";
            else
            echo $val;
            echo "</td>";}
        }
    echo "</tr>";   
    }



?>

</table>
</div>


I work on this these day but still get this display error thank you

![enter image description here][1]
```

[image]

Comment: I cant find any error...

Comment: I have tried your code and it outputs something like this...

Comment: test.xlsx Result

Import from spreadsheet files
Unname coloum 0  Unname coloum 1  Unname coloum 2  Unname coloum 3  Unname coloum 4  Unname coloum 5  Email address
1 10072011_1 Project Report N/A ABC airuser kamal.joshi@mail.com
2 TEST Test Te TEE TEST joshi.kamal@mail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my tried code that uses ur logic.. I have passed excel file.(test.xlsx)

```
<?php
    /** PHPExcel */
    include_once('PHPExcel.php');

    /** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
    include_once('PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php');

    include_once('PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php');

    //$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $file = 'test.xlsx';
    $readerType = 'Excel2007';

    $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($readerType);
$PHPExcel = $reader->load($file);
$sheet = $PHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($sheet->getHighestColumn());

$pattern="/^[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$/";

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){
for ($head = 0; $head < $highestColumn; $head++){
$testMail = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($head, $row)->getValue();
if (preg_match($pattern,$testMail))
$mailColumn=$head;
}}
if(!isset($mailColumn))
{die('No email column detected, please check your file and import again.');}


$invaild[] = NULL ;
$email[] = NULL ;
$duplicate[] = NULL ;

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $highestColumn; $y++) {
    $val = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($y, $row)->getValue();

    if ($y == $mailColumn && !preg_match($pattern,$val))
    {$invaild[]=$row;}
    elseif ($y == $mailColumn && in_array($val,$email))
    {$duplicate[]=$val;
    $duplicate[]=$row;}
    //elseif (!in_array($row,$duplicate) && !in_array($row,$invaild) )
    //{echo $val;}

    if ($y == $mailColumn)
    {$email[]=$val;
    $email=array_unique($email);}

  }
}
$invaild=array_unique($invaild);


/*foreach ($invaild as $c)
{echo $c;}
echo "<br>";
foreach ($duplicate as $d)
{echo $d;}*/

?>


<div id="stylized" class="view">
<h1><?php echo $file.' Result';?></h1> 
<p>Import from spreadsheet files</p>
   <div id="container">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="viewImport">
<thead>
<tr>

<?php
for ($head = 0; $head < $highestColumn; $head++){
if ($head==$mailColumn)
echo "<th field='col' $head> Email address </th>";
else
echo "<th field='col' $head> Unname coloum $head </th>";
}
?>
</tr>
</thead>

<?php
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
            //Here I have added condition
    if (!in_array($row,$duplicate) && !in_array($row,$invaild)){
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    for ($y = 0; $y < $highestColumn; $y++) {
        if (!in_array($row,$duplicate) && !in_array($row,$invaild)){
            $val = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($y, $row)->getValue();
            echo "<td>";
            if (!$val)
            echo "-";
            else
            echo $val;
            echo "</td>";}
        }
            //Here I have added condition
    if (!in_array($row,$duplicate) && !in_array($row,$invaild)){
        echo "</tr>";   
    }
    }



?>

</table>
</div>
```

Here is source of the output.

```
<div id="stylized" class="view">
<h1>test.xlsx Result</h1> 
<p>Import from spreadsheet files</p>
   <div id="container">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="viewImport">
<thead>
<tr>

<th field='col' 0> Unname coloum 0 </th><th field='col' 1> Unname coloum 1 </th><th field='col' 2> Unname coloum 2 </th><th field='col' 3> Unname coloum 3 </th><th field='col' 4> Unname coloum 4 </th><th field='col' 5> Unname coloum 5 </th><th field='col' 6> Email address </th>  </tr>

</thead>

<tr><td>1</td><td>REP_10072011_1</td><td>Project </td><td>N/A</td><td>Me</td><td>TEST1</td><td>kamal.joshi@mail.com</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>TEST</td><td>Test</td><td>Te</td><td>TEE</td><td>TEST</td><td>joshi.kamal@mail.com</td></tr> 
</table>

</div>
```

Well I have tried dataTable jQuery Plugin and its working perfectly..
Have a look at the link http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1283/warning-unexpected-number-of-td-elements./p1

[image: Well I have attached image of my output..]

My suggestion : please go thru your jquery dataTables plugin integration. Make sure that you are including required jquery in your output page of excel sheet with matching class or id selector like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#viewImport').dataTable();
} );
```

Edit : Check this out...

```
<?php
    /** PHPExcel */
    include_once('PHPExcel.php');

    /** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
    include_once('PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php');

    include_once('PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php');

    //$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $file = 'test.xlsx';
    $readerType = 'Excel2007';

    $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($readerType);
$PHPExcel = $reader->load($file);
$sheet = $PHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($sheet->getHighestColumn());

$pattern="/^[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$/";

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){
for ($head = 0; $head < $highestColumn; $head++){
$testMail = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($head, $row)->getValue();
if (preg_match($pattern,$testMail))
$mailColumn=$head;
}}
if(!isset($mailColumn))
{die('No email column detected, please check your file and import again.');}


$invaild[] = NULL ;
$email[] = NULL ;
$duplicate[] = NULL ;

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $highestColumn; $y++) {
    $val = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($y, $row)->getValue();

    if ($y == $mailColumn && !preg_match($pattern,$val))
    {$invaild[]=$row;}
    elseif ($y == $mailColumn && in_array($val,$email))
    {$duplicate[]=$val;
    $duplicate[]=$row;}
    //elseif (!in_array($row,$duplicate) && !in_array($row,$invaild) )
    //{echo $val;}

    if ($y == $mailColumn)
    {$email[]=$val;
    $email=array_unique($email);}

  }
}
$invaild=array_unique($invaild);


/*foreach ($invaild as $c)
{echo $c;}
echo "<br>";
foreach ($duplicate as $d)
{echo $d;}*/

?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#viewImport').dataTable();
        } );
</script>
<div id="stylized" class="view">
<h1><?php echo $file.' Result';?></h1> 
<p>Import from spreadsheet files</p>
   <div id="container">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="viewImport">
<thead>
<tr>

<?php
for ($head = 0; $head < $highestColumn; $head++){
if ($head==$mailColumn)
echo "<th field='col' $head> Email address </th>";
else
echo "<th field='col' $head> Unname coloum $head </th>";
}
?>
</tr>
</thead>

<?php
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    if (!in_array($row,$duplicate) && !in_array($row,$invaild)){
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    for ($y = 0; $y < $highestColumn; $y++) {
        if (!in_array($row,$duplicate) && !in_array($row,$invaild)){
            $val = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($y, $row)->getValue();
            echo "<td>";
            if (!$val)
            echo "-";
            else
            echo $val;
            echo "</td>";}
        }
    if (!in_array($row,$duplicate) && !in_array($row,$invaild)){
        echo "</tr>";   
    }
    }



?>

</table>
</div>
```

Comment: So from your image, i guess you are using dataTable plugin of jquery... Let me try and will get back to you soon...

Comment: Here i have attached image of my output... Even I have provide you link. Might be that can be helpful to you..

Comment: Sorry would you print out an array result? In my trail it is not capture start from the second line

Comment: Thank you for your help . As the bounty is close to end and you make a great effort on it. I will post the question after i try to solve some of it.  I look forward to have you take a look

Comment: Glad that you have update the code, do you know are there any option i can edit the column header in this plugin? As you can see that currently i auto - generate a unname column + number and it would be nice if the user can directly edit and save a new column header

Comment: If that does not support , i have a naive idea that put a text input box in the header, but much better if there is natural support in the plugin